# A stored procedure to select from three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have these three tables

**Courses**

```
course ID     course Name     course start time   course end time
1             Math            10:00:00            11:00:00
2             Science         11:00:00            12:00:00
3             geography       09:00:00            10:00:00
```

**student_courses**

```
course ID     student ID      Final cost
1             2               100
2             3               200
```

**Students**

```
student ID     student name
1              AAAA
2              BBBB
```

I need a select statement to place in a stored procedure to only return [Course ID], [Course name] column values of the courses that a student is not enrolled in (achieved)

**AND** check the student current courses' start and end times and only return courses in which times the student is available (doesn't have a class)

my select statement that only return courses that the student is not enrolled in::

```
SELECT [Course ID], [Course name] 
FROM Courses
WHERE [Course ID] NOT IN 
 (SELECT Course ID from student_courses WHERE [student ID]=1)
```

How can i edit this statement to include the available time condition (knowing i want to put it in a stored procedure)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you need:

```
SELECT [Course ID], [Course name] 
FROM Courses 
WHERE [Course ID] NOT IN 
 (SELECT Course ID from student_courses sc
  INNER JOIN Courses c ON sc.[course ID] = c.[course ID] 
  WHERE [student ID] = 1
  AND (c.[course start time] BETWEEN Courses.[course start time] AND Courses.[course end time]
  OR c.[course end time] BETWEEN Courses.[course start time] AND Courses.[course end time]))
```

I see no reason, why this should be in a `stored procedure`. A `view` might be reasonable.

Read more about [`views` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).

Comment: Note that `BETWEEN` is including the boundaries. It's not clear if that's what you wish. If not simply rewrite with `(starttime > ... and starttime < ...) or end time ...`

Comment: it gives me the following error:: the data types date and time  are incompatible in the less than or equal to operator.

Comment: What datatype are your columns? Also this doesn't make sense. The error suggests, that different datatypes are compared to each other. But here one datatype is compared with itself, it's the same table. And if you google sql server and your errormessage there are no results. So either you gave us wrong information or not enough.

Comment: [course start time], [course start time] are both of type time(7). the error says that you cant compare time or type date in less than or equal to operators.

Comment: Execute this query: `select top 1
* from whateverTable
where 
'01:00:00' < '02:00:00'` and there will be results. Change the `<` to `>` and there will be no results. If that doesn't work, there's something seriously wrong with your RDBMS, whichever you are using, and SQL Server it's not for sure. Cause comparing times in whatever is definitely possible and there's no function required for that.

Comment: Another wtf, `time` has no `(7)` behind. It's just `time`

Comment: can use c.[course start time] which is not  BETWEEN Courses.[course start time] AND Courses.[course end time]......... how can write that???

Comment: The exact same way you wrote it. `NOT BETWEEN`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21081/discussion-between-hammam-muhareb-and-tombom)